# How to go to next HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Suppose I have a basic HTML page with five text boxes and one button at the end.

Now I want to go to the next HTML element, let's say next TextBox (same as the <kbd>Tab</kbd> does), on press of key code **412** and on press of key code **417**, I should be able to go back to the previous element (same as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Now I can not use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or you can say <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is absent on my keyboard. Any help?

Well the code to detect key press is below:

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck()

{

   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   document.Form1.KeyName.value = event.keyCode;

  switch(KeyID)

   {

      case 412:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Rewind Pressed";

      break; 

      case 417:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Forward Pressed";

      break;
      ....................
}
```

Now I want to do the Next and Prev on Key code 412 and 417

Comment: :-/ How do you plan to enter text without the "N" and "P" keys?

Comment: Next *HTML element* is different than next  *input element*. What do you want?

Comment: @Felix Kling , @Aaron Digulla Updated question with sample Code. I want to go to Next element , whether it be a Text Box , Button or Image

Comment: will your users be missing their tab key (assuming you're not the only one who will be using this form)? That's whom you should design for.

Comment: @outis, Yes the User will be Missing The tab Key on their Key Board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build array with all the elements in the desired order:

```
var _arrElements = [ "myInput1", "myInput2", "myInput3" ];
```

Second, change your code to detect the textbox from which key was pressed, find its ID in the array and focus the proper textbox before or after it:

```
function KeyCheck(evt) {
    if (typeof evt == "undefined" || !evt)
        evt = window.event; //IE...

    var KeyID = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var flag = 0;
    switch(KeyID) {
        case 34:
            flag = -1; //Backward
            break; 
         case 33:
             flag = 1; //Forward
             break;
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return; //key is not relevant

    var sender = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if (!sender)
        return; //key up did not come from valid element

    var nIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < _arrElements.length; i++) {
        if (sender.id == _arrElements[i]) {
            nIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (nIndex < 0)
        return; //key up did not come from valid textbox

    var newIndex = nIndex + flag;
    if (newIndex >= _arrElements.length)
        newIndex = 0;
    if (newIndex < 0)
        newIndex = _arrElements.length - 1;
    document.getElementById(_arrElements[newIndex]).focus();
}
```

Live test case with the complete code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/vAh8R/

In the example I'm using `Page Up`/`Page Down`, no idea what keys produce the codes you gave.

Edit: you can put ID of every focusable element you want in the array, it doesn't have to be only textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the elements in a `div` and add a `keypress` event handler to it.

This page has an example at the bottom: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the previous and next DOM siblings (if any) with the [`previousSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-640FB3C8) and [`nextSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F) properties, the previous and next element siblings (if any) with the [`previousElementSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-previousElementSibling) and [`nextElementSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-nextElementSibling) properties. If the elements you want to move between aren't all sibling of each other, this becomes trickier. A JS library would be a big help, simplifying traversal.

You could also pre-process forms using the [`elements`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) property, creating a collection of inputs in [`tabIndex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40676705) order and keeping track of the current input, updating whenever the user presses the appropriate key or when an input gains or loses focus.

DOM based approach (untested, <del>possibly</del>probably buggy):

```
if (! Array.prototype.append) {
    Array.prototype.append = function(arr) {
        this.push.apply(this, arr);
    }
}
if (! Array.prototype.each) {
    Array.prototype.each = function(f) {
        for (var i=0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            f(this[i], i);
        }
    }
}
if (! Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(f) {
        var other = [];
        if (!f) {
            f = function (x) {return x;};
        }
        for (var i=0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            if (f(this[i])) {
                other.push(this[i]);
            }
        }
        return other;
    }
}

// call this on the form element
function keyNavigation(form, nextKey, prevKey, modifier) {
    if (nextKey) {
        nextKey = nextKey.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        nextKey = 'n';
    }
    if (prevKey) {
        prevKey = prevKey.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        prevKey = 'p';
    }
    switch (modifier) {
    case 'ctrlKey':
    case 'altKey':
    case 'metaKey':
        break;
    case 'ctrl':
    case 'alt':
    case 'meta':
        modifier += 'Key';
        break;
    default:
        modifier = 'ctrlKey';
        break;
    }
    var inputs=[], assigned = [], unassigned=[], input, j=0;
    for (var i=0; i < form.elements.length; ++i) {
        input = form.elements[i];
        if (input.tabIndex) {
            j = input.tabIndex;
            while(assigned[j]) {++j}
            assigned[j] = input;
        } else if (!input.disabled) {
            unassigned.push(input);
        }
    }
    inputs = assigned.filter();
    inputs.append(unassigned);
    inputs.each(function (input, keyedIdx) {
        input.keyedIdx = keyedIdx;
    });

    var currIdx;

    form.gotoNextInput = function() {
        // if currIdx is undefined, comparison should be false
        if (currIdx+1 < inputs.length) {
            inputs[++currIdx].focus();
        }
    }
    form.gotoPreviousInput = function() {
        // if currIdx is undefined, comparison should be false
        if (currIdx && currIdx > 0) {
            inputs[++currIdx].focus();
        }
    }
    form.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
            if (evt[modifier]) {
                switch (String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode).toLowerCase()) {
                    case nextKey:
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        this.gotoNextInput();
                        return false;
                    case prevKey:
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        this.gotoPreviousInput();
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }, true);
    // programmatic setting of focus above should invoke this
    // handler. Wasteful, but not problematic.
    form.addEventListener('focus', function (evt) {
            if (typeof evt.target.keyedIdx == 'number') {
                currIdx = evt.target.keyedIdx;
            }
        }, true);
    form.addEventListener('blur', function (evt) {
            delete currIdx;
        }, true);
}
```